# Canvas app direct link

Tags: page-layout, contact, canvas

We have canvas app which loads list of items. (Here all oauth is established). From this user is able to click on individual link to open the item details from there.

Now I am looking for direct way to point to item from one of the layout page example Contact layout page. What would be best way to achieved this?

Create anothe canvas app looks overkill. Is there better alternative?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Mashup or just a link from Contact detail page to the Canvas App?

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is having a button on detail page of Contact record, on click of that button you want to open the canvas. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes want to open canvas app, but with additional param to be passed so that it opens differently on the iframed url ..

Comment: Hi @Mr.Frodo could you help if there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you look at my answer and links provided in that? Where are you stuck exctly?

Comment: Yes. But couldn't figure out how to create link betwen the two ..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are aware of [Canvas events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_events.htm)(**Publish and Subscribe**). This is a wonderful way of passing information between salesforce and external app.

I wrote [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/124479/20721) a while back, It might be helpful for you.